# How can I specify the order that before_filters are executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

Does rails make any guarantees about the order that before filters get executed with either of the following usages:

```
before_filter [:fn1, :fn2]
```

or

```
before_filter :fn1
before_filter :fn2
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you refer http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html, there is a subheading called "Filter chain ordering", here is the example code from that:

```
class ShoppingController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :verify_open_shop

class CheckoutController < ShoppingController
    prepend_before_filter :ensure_items_in_cart, :ensure_items_in_stock
```

According to the explanation:

> The filter chain for the `CheckoutController` is now
>   `:ensure_items_in_cart`, `:ensure_items_in_stock`,
>   `:verify_open_shop.`

So you can explicitly give the order of the filter chain like that.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.. @Johnny You're a life safer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sector and JohnnyWoo: Your links to http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html have gone dead.

Comment: On rails 3.2.14, the filter chain I get is the following : :ensure_items_in_stock, :ensure_items_in_cart, :verify_open_shop

Comment: Updated link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html

Comment: A command to output and debug the exact filter chain would be helpful.

Answer (score 25):

Before_filter Order in Rails
http://b2.broom9.com/?p=806

Filter chain ordering
http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html

If you need guarantee order, you may do this:

```
before_filter :fn3

def fn3
  fn1
  fn2
end
```

Comment: Won't that cause problems if both fail, and try to redirect?

Comment: You can use if in fn3 with check return result of fn1, fn2

Comment: If fn1 fails (ie returns false) and doesn't need to execute fn2, you have to add a bit more logic. Something like: `fn1 ? fn2 : false`

Answer (score 3):

as far as I can tell, you put the first function you want to execute and so forth.

So, something like:

```
before_filter :fn1, :fn2

def fn1
  puts 'foo'
end

def fn2
  puts 'bar'
end
```

Would execute `fn1`, then `fn2`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using Rails 4 and even when my order is `:fn1, :fn2`, :fn2 is getting called first.

Answer (score 2):

The filter chain for the `CheckoutController` does not follow this order

```
:ensure_items_in_cart, :ensure_items_in_stock, :verify_open_shop
```

Instead, it should be

```
:ensure_items_in_stock, :ensure_items_in_cart, :verify_open_shop
```