# What order do before filters occur in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, before-filter

What order do before filters occur in? Specifically, what order do the before_action filters occur in, in regards to inheiritance? For example, will this work:

```
class A < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_user

  def set_user
    @user = something
  end
end

class B < A
  before_action :set_post

  def show
    render @post
  end

  def set_post
    @post = @user.posts.first
  end
end
```

Will `B#show` work? What are the rules for filter order for future reference? I can't find any of this in the Rails documentation.

Comment: Doesn't have your ```A``` class inherit from some controller like *ActionController* ? If an action is performed on ```B``` instance, inherited filters like ```set_user``` are called first.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Comment: how to fix the order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711797/how-can-i-specify-the-order-that-before-filters-are-executed

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at **[the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f53132deea65ae673b29b811c606be103f1ae3ab/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L80)** and **[API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html)** on filters.

The default ordering should be

1. `:set_post`
2. `:set_user`

I think if you wanted to push `:set_user` to the top of the stack you could change the line in `A` to

```
prepend_before_action :set_user
```

Also worth pointing out, this isn't the only question on the topic; there are [others here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711797/how-can-i-specify-the-order-that-before-filters-are-executed).

---

As for your specific situation, it looks like you'll need to change `A` as I mentioned above in order to have `@user` be assigned by the time `set_post` in `B` runs.

---

As of 4.2.6 (probably changed in an earlier version), the ordering is now parent before child:

1. `:set_user`
2. `:set_post`

Comment: You have the default ordering (above) backwards. The before_filters on the derived class (B) is called before the base class (A) before_filters. So it is: 1. :set_user, and 2. :set_post

Also note, after_filters are called in reverse order, the most derived first.

Comment: I just tried this on Rails 4.2 and it looks that this is not valid anymore. Parent class's callback is executed first and then child's class callback. So: 1) `set_user`, 2) `set_post`

Comment: It'd be great if you'd suggest an edit on the answer directly.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is no longer true as of Rails 4.2.6.  It was probably changed earlier, but that's the version I'm on right now.

Parent filters are now called before child filters, so the ordering will now be:

1. `:set_user`
2. `:set_post`

And, if you think about it, that ordering really makes more sense.  As previously said, if you need the child to call the filter before the parent, you need to use `prepend_before_action`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code will work as intended.

The before_filters on the derived class (B) are called before the before_filters on the base class (A). So the order of the methods called are:

1. set_user()
2. set_post()
3. show()

Also note, after_filters are called in reverse order, the most derived first.

Comment: As you said, the before_filter in the derived class is called first, as B is the derived class, set_post will be called first, and then set_user.