# Why before_filters on subcontrollers are called before the before filters on parent controllers on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using `Rails 3.2.X`

I have Controllers inheritance case as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :do_something

  protected

  def do_something
  end
end
```

and

```
class ChildController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :do_something_else

  protected

  def do_something_else
  end
end
```

When calling actions on `ChildController` I see `do_something_else` to be called before `do_something`. Is that the expected behavior?

Even if I do:

```
append_before_filter :do_something_else
```

the `do_something_else` is always called first, which is not what I expected.

How can I make the `before_filters` defined on a sub-controller to be executed after the `before_filters` defined on its parent controller.

[UPDATE] Please note that the question is more general. I need an answer that will cover for any number of before filters on `ApplicationController` and any number of before filters on sub-controllers and sub-controllers of sub-controllers, on longer inheritance trees.

To make this update more clear:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :do_something1
  before_filter :do_something2
end

class ChildController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :do_something3
  before_filter :do_somethign4
end

class Child2Controller < ChildController
  before_filter :do_something5
  before_filter :do_somethign6
end
```

calling actions on `Child2Controller` should be called: 1) `do_something1` 2) `do_something2` 3) `do_something3` 4) `do_something4` 5) `do_something5` 6) `do_something6`

But they do not seem to be called like that.

So what's the trick?

Comment: Adding a comment hoping that others will not waste hours debugging like I just did.  This behavior (child filter before parent) applies to Rails 3.x only, which is why the question is closed.  As of at least 4.2 (likely 4.0), parent filters are called BEFORE child filters.

Answer (score 6):

Instead, try to `prepend` the `ApplicationController` `before_filter`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  prepend_before_filter :do_something

  ...
end
```

There are a few other questions in this space on this topic. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18582647/2241124) addresses this very issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepend_before_filter` for the method in `ApplicationController` if you want it to be executed first.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  prepend_before_filter :do_something

  protected

  def do_something
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe that this does not answer my question. What if I have 5 before_filters on ApplicationController and 5 on sub-controller. How shall I define them? and what if the Sub-controller is further sub-classed with another controller class that has 5 more before_filters?