# Devise precedence before filters of scope controller and application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am confused about sequence of the execution of before filters between application controller before filter and Users controller before filter.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  befor_filter :check_me

  def check_me
   puts "checked!"
  end
end


class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

I thought it should execute `check_me` and then `authenticate_user!`. But it was not. What is the proper sequence here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callbacks are appended as we go up in hierarchy.

That means `UsersController` callbacks would appear first and then `ApplicationController`.

The sequence of execution would be:

1. `authenticate_user!`
2. `check_me`

If you want to change the precedence, then add `prepend_before_filter`.

Example:  `prepend_befor_filter :check_me`

Refer: [What order do before filters occur in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582400/what-order-do-before-filters-occur-in)

Comment: Thanks. But my cases `prepend_befor_filter` was not working.

Comment: try using `prepend_before_action` instead. Deprecation note for `prepend_before_filter` : https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes/issues/141