# A before_filter does not see value assigned in another before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to access one variable set in a method from another method. This is in Rails 1.9 code below.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :method1
  before_filter :method2
  def method1
    @remote_user = 'dev_user'
  end
  def method2
    unless @remote_user.present?
      render :status => 401, :text => "Authentication failed"
      false
    end
  end
```

When attempting to access it in the second method, it is always returning blank. The 401 is always returning with the text `"Authentication failed"`. Could someone advise on to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I do not think that is it because if I add @remote_user = 'dev_user' immediately before the unless statement it is not returning the 401 and "Authentication Failed"

Comment: It is because `@remote_user` is only initialized in `method1`,it is not initialized in `method2`.

Comment: There is no such thing as Rails 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to guarantee that a method is called before another on before_filter, do something like this:

```
before_filter :fn3

def fn3
  fn1
  fn2
end
```

from -> [How can I specify the order that before_filters are executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711797/how-can-i-specify-the-order-that-before-filters-are-executed)

Hope it helps

**EDITED**

Better yet, use prepend_before_filter for anything you needs to be resolved before the before_filter method.

in your case:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery
      prepend_before_filter :method1
      before_filter :method2
      def method1
        @remote_user = 'dev_user'
      end
      def method2
        unless @remote_user.present?
          render :status => 401, :text => "Authentication failed"
        false
      end
    end
```

Comment: I just tried this and it STILL does not work.  I think the method is being called it is just not setting the value in some inexplicable way

Answer (score 0):

To ensure correct order of `before_filter` you can use `prepend_before_filter` or `append_before_filter`. Imho `prepend` is the default behaviour, so your filters are executed in reverse order.

So to fix this you will have to write:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :method2
  prepend_before_filter :method1
```

You could just write `before_filter` twice (in this order) and it would be fine, but this is imho more expresssive. First write all the `before_filters` for which the order does not matter, and then `prepend` the one that needs to be first.

Alternatively you could write

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :method1
  append_before_filter :method2
```

which does exactly the same, but makes sure method2 is executed last. Whichever you prefer :)

Also note that filters defined in other controllers (deriving from ApplicationController) will normally be executed first!

Comment: What happens if there is a filter in a controller derived from ApplicationController that is calling a method of the same name with a different definition?

Comment: The local definition overrules the definition in the application controller. Imho this means that the `before_filter` defined in the application controller will call the method in the derived controller. So if you have an extra `before_filter` with the same name in the derived class, it will be called twice.