# before_filter running out of order, working fine in dev and staging env. but not working on qa env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> We have following filters in controller:

```
  before_action :authenticate_api_request!, except: [:reply_messages]
  before_action :community_uuid
  before_action :is_user_blocked?, only: [:create, :like, :dislike, :flag, :reply_message]
  before_action :user_confirmed_email?, only: [:create]
  before_action :get_message, only: [:like, :dislike, :flag, :remove, :get_message_json, :reply_message, :reply_messages]
  before_action :get_reply_message, only: [:reply_message]
  before_action :get_group, only: [:create]
  before_action :is_blocked_from_group?, only: [:create, :like, :dislike, :reply_message]
```

and order in which they are executed is:

```
user_confirmed_email?
get_message
get_reply_message
authenticate_api_request!
community_uuid
is_user_blocked?
get_group
is_blocked_from_group?
```

The problem here is `authenticate_api_request!, community_uuid and is_user_blocked?` is called after `user_confirmed_email?`.

**Its working properly in dev and staging environment but not working same code on qa server, didn't get why this happen even replicate same code.**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I specify the order that before\_filters are executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711797/how-can-i-specify-the-order-that-before-filters-are-executed)

Comment: There is no duplication of filter "Its working properly in dev and staging environment but not working same code on qa server, didn't get why this happen even replicate same code."

Answer (score 0):

Check [Filter Chain Ordering](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9745492/8304905).

You have to specify `:prepend_before_filter` so that your filters are executed on the beginning of the chain.

Notice that `:prepend_before_action` is an alias of `:prepend_before_filter`, [prepend_before_action](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/prepend_before_action).

I haven't tried it myself but you might write something like:

```
  before_action :user_confirmed_email?, only: [:create]
  before_action :get_message, only: [:like, :dislike, :flag, :remove, :get_message_json, :reply_message, :reply_messages]
  before_action :get_reply_message, only: [:reply_message]
  before_action :get_group, only: [:create]
  before_action :is_blocked_from_group?, only: [:create, :like, :dislike, :reply_message]  
  prepend_before_action :is_user_blocked?, only: [:create, :like, :dislike, :flag, :reply_message]
  prepend_before_action :community_uuid
  prepend_before_action :authenticate_api_request!, except: [:reply_messages]
```

Comment: We don't need this due to "Its working properly in dev and staging environment but not working same code on qa server, didn't get why this happen even replicate same code."